# Instantiating subclasses in java

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract class like so:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    protected String greeting;

    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

... and a subclass like so:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {

    public MyClass() {
        this.greeting = "Hello, World!";
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyAbstractClass c = new MyClass();
        c.run();
    }
}
```

I'm going to be creating multiple subclasses, all of them will have the same main method that just instantiates the subclass.  Is there a cleaner way of writing this so I don't need to duplicate the main method in every subclass with a different subclass name?  So if I create a new subclass called `MyOtherClass` I don't need to put a main method in with `MyAbstractClass c = new MyOtherClass();`

I guess I can do it the other way round, where I run the main from the abstract class and instantiate the subclass in there, but then each time I want to change which subclass is instantiated I'd obviously need to change the class name after `new`.  I suppose what I'm looking for is a way to define the main method in the abstract class in such a way that when I run the subclass, it instantiates a copy of the subclass and not the abstract class.  If that makes sense...

Comment: Why do you need a `main` method in each subclass? Do you know what the purpose of a `main` method is?

Comment: Well...there's only going to be one `main` that actually runs, so perhaps you should condense all of your subclass instantiations into one driver-esque class (a class that *only* has `main` in it)?

Comment: The abstract class has functionality which does common stuff like I/O.  The subclasses each process the input differently.  So I'd be running the subclass against a specific input.

Comment: `static` method can't be overridden. it can be redefined only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a good fit for the [factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Try something like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    protected String greeting;

    public void run() {
        doSomething();
    }

    public abstract void doSomething();

    public abstract MyAbstractClass makeClass();

}

public class MyClass1 extends MyAbstractClass {

    public MyClass1() {
        this.greeting = "Hello, World!";
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }

    @Override
    public MyAbstractClass makeClass() {
        return new MyClass1();
    }

}
```

Then, whenever you need to create a specific instance just call `makeClass()` in a single implementation of the `main()` method located in the place you consider most convenient, for instance in `MyAbstractClass`:

```
MyAbstractClass mac = new MyClass1();
MyAbstractClass obj = mac.makeClass();
```

The last line will return an appropriate instance depending on the class used for instantiating the concrete object.

Comment: Well I suppose what I was trying to get away from really was having a common method in every subclass that did the exact same thing but with a different subclass name.  Your example just moves the problem from `main` to `makeClass()`

Comment: @conorgriffin in a way yes, it moves the responsibilities from one place to another - but there's no escaping, at _some_ place the objects need to be instantiated and it makes sense to put this code in each subclass; and on the other hand - a Java application can only have a _single_ `main()` method, so it was necessary to get rid of the multiple `main()` methods.

Comment: Well each of these subclasses is an application in it's own right.  They are actually small programs for solving programming challenges.  They have common functionality though like reading in the input file and writing the output so I kept that functionality in the abstract class and put the problem-specific logic in the subclasses.  Hence they all have their own main right now so I can run them in isolation

Answer (score 2):

This is where dynamic class loading can be useful. If all your subclasses agree to have a no-arg constructor, you can simply use a single Main class with the main method, and pass the class to use as argument:

```
java com.foo.bar.Main com.foo.bar.MyFrouteenthSubclass
```

The main method would simply look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String className = args[0];
    MyAbstractClass object = (MyAbstractClass) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
    object.run();
}
```

You could also assign a name to all your subclasses and store on instance of each of them in a `Map<String, MyAbstractClass>`, and simply call the main class with the name of the class as argument:

```
java com.foo.bar.Main fourteen
```

Comment: Actually, not quite what I want but maybe this is as close as I can get.  I would like to have a main in the abstract class that instantiates whichever subclass gets run.